# Dados truncados LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql

Estou com um problema com o load data, tentando fazer a inserção do arquivo CSV os dados ficam truncados pois em campos como comentários ou no endereço.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'exemplo.csv'
                INTO TABLE relat_produt_analistas_temp
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
                IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Essa é a query que estou utilizando.
E como este relatório que recebo vem de outra empresa, não posso mudar a maneira como ele é gerado.
alguém sabe como posso eliminar comandos 
`\t` e `\r\n` extras que devem ser a possível causa do problema?